# Select from table by knowing only date without time (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to retrieve records from table by knowing the date in column contains date and time.

Suppose I have table called `t1` which contains only two column `name` and `date` respectively.

The data stored in column date like this `8/3/2010 12:34:20 PM`.

I want to retrieve this record by this query for example (note I don't put the time):

```
Select * From t1 Where date="8/3/2010"
```

This query give me nothing !

How can I retrieve `date` by knowing only `date` without the time?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, so I'm using column-name `your_date` instead.

If you have an index on `your_date`, I would use

```
WHERE your_date >= TO_DATE('2010-08-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND your_date <  TO_DATE('2010-08-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE your_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2010-08-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                    AND TO_DATE('2010-08-03 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

If there is no index or if there are not too many records

```
WHERE TRUNC(your_date) = TO_DATE('2010-08-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

should be sufficient. [`TRUNC`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm) without parameter removes hours, minutes and seconds from a `DATE`.

---

If performance really matters, consider putting a [`Function Based Index`](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html) on that column:

```
CREATE INDEX trunc_date_idx ON t1(TRUNC(your_date));
```

Comment: @Abdulrhman - you should accept the answer that worked for you!

Comment: trunk() worked like a charm, sweet like chocolate! I should have read your post early.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov: I don't see how this would happen, please have a look at a row that is returned by one query but not the other and try to investigate what happens. BTW, there is no `<=`, only `<`.

Comment: TRUNK + TO_DATE works! Also makes easier because its not so nice write those YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format

Comment: For some reason, if you use `>=` or `between`, indexing is not used

Comment: @ACV: It is used with my tests, but it depends on your table statistics and the percentage of rows that the optimizer expects for your given range.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLang. You're right, it's because of I was basically getting back more than 50%-60% of the total rows so the engine decided not to use indexes at all.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I usually go with:

```
select * 
from   t1
where  date between trunc( :somedate )          -- 00:00:00
            and     trunc( :somedate ) + .99999 -- 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert your date column to the correct format and compare:

```
SELECT * From my_table WHERE to_char(my_table.my_date_col,'MM/dd/yyyy') = '8/3/2010'
```

This part

```
to_char(my_table.my_date_col,'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Will result in string *'8/3/2010'*

Comment: Must be carefull with this approach. Insteand choose 'yyyy/mm/MM' when you need date ranges

Answer (score 3):

`trunc(my_date,'DD')` will give you just the date and not the time in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the between function to get all records between 2010-08-03 00:00:00:000 AND 2010-08-03 23:59:59:000

Comment: `BETWEEN` means `>= AND <=`, so your query would return rows with `date = 2010-08-04 00:00:00` too.

Comment: Good catch, fixed. Your answer was much more thorough +1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this one:

```sql
select * from t1 where to_date(date_column)='8/3/2010'
```

Comment: Have you tested this query in oracle?

Comment: This query, in oracle, results in an error: `ORA-01843: not a valid month`.

Answer (score -1):

> Try the following way.

```
Select * from t1 where date(col_name)="8/3/2010"
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work with Oracle. Gives me an `ORA-00936: missing expression`.

Comment: In Oracle, double-quotes are used to delimit an identifier; single quotes are used for string literals.

Comment: Date() doesn't work in Oracle. For example, `SELECT date(sysdate) FROM dual;` **ERROR at line 1:ORA-00936: missing expression **