# How to Use Where clause with Datetime to Update records

Tags: mysql, datetime, where-clause

Can I know what is wrong with my sql statement below. I gives an error "incorrect datetime value".

```
UPDATE stocks SET  Notes = '0' where ExpireDate like '%2017-12-28%' and StockCount > 0;
```

Comment: did you try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399753/select-from-table-by-knowing-only-date-without-time-oracle

Comment: don't use like and % with timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET sql_safe_updates = 0;
UPDATE STOCKS
SET NOTES = '0'
WHERE EXPIREDATE = CURDATE()
AND STOCKCOUNT > 0;
SET sql_safe_updates = 1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a54e7d/1)

Comment: It still does not work. Gives the error "You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode"

Comment: Actually what I need is to get today's date and if it matches with the expire date of a product, change the status to expire.. please tell me if there is any other way to do this or if there is any mistake in my sql.